# Summing values by matching property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need help summing values by matching object properties. So for example, one object might look like this:

```
{
  proc_nm: 'postgres-loader',
  count: '290',
  date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
}
```

I would like to sum the `count` values of the objects that have a matching property, like with `NAMES('postgres-loader' etc)`.

How can this be done?

Comment: You could `filter` then `reduce`: `data.filter((d) => d.proc_nm == 'postgres-loader').reduce((prev, cur) => prev += cur.count, 0)` Assuming `data` is an array of the object in the question.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of array entries that match, or do you want to sum those values?

Comment: *"a JSON snippet"*: that is not JSON. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag, and reconsider how you use the JSON word.

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = ['postgres-loader', 'postgres-connector', 'postgres-reader'];

const variables = [
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-connector',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-loader',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-writer',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    }
];

let count = 0;

variables.forEach((variable) => {
    if (names.includes(variable.proc_nm)) count++;
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` is an option.

```js
const variables = [
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-connector',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-loader',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-writer',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    }
];

let count = 0;
variables.forEach(x => {
    count += x.proc_nm === 'postgres-connector';
});

console.log(count);
```

**Array.prototype.forEach** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

If you want to group by the specific `proc_nm` and count how many objects have the same value you can use `reduce`

```js
const variables = [
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-connector',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-loader',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-writer',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    },
    {
        proc_nm: 'postgres-writer',
        count: '290',
        date_trunc: '2021-11-03T14:00:00.000Z'
    }
];

var result = [];
variables.reduce((res, value) => {
  if (!res[value.proc_nm]) {
    res[value.proc_nm] = { proc_nm: value.proc_nm, count: 0 };
    result.push(res[value.proc_nm])
  }
  res[value.proc_nm].count += 1;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```